# Best design pattern for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a meta-search engine system, i implemented mainly using static classes. The query pre processing module consists of the following static methods

```
function queryPreprocessing() { } 
queryPreProcessing.removeStopWords = function (query){ // code here}
queryPreProcessing.stemmer = function (w) { //code here }
queryPreProcessing.convertBoolean = function (w){ //code here}
```

Technically the query pre processing modules takes as input a string (the query) and performs the above named functions on it. For example:

```
var query = $("#textbox").val();
query = queryPreProcessing.removeStopWords(query) ; 
query = queryPreProcessing.stemmer(query) ; 
query = queryPreProcessing.convertBoolean(query) ;
```

For simplicity, it was easier for me to make all the methods static and call them when needed but my question is: Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to use the Object prototype here is how I would structure it:

```
// uses Object.extend for the constructor https://gist.github.com/rlemon/5256375

function Query(options) {
  this.value; // I would store the value in the object itself. Otherwise you should use this as a utility object and not deal with prototype. 
  // other defaults
  Object.extend(this, options); // extend options to the object
}

Query.prototype = {
  constructor: Query,
  removeStopWords: function() { .. return this;},
  stemmer: function() { .. return this;},
  convertBoolean: function() { .. return this;} // returns itself for chaining
};

var q = new Query({ value: ' Foo Bar Hello World ' });
q.removeStopWords().stemmer().convertBoolean();
alert(q.value);
```

But this is how I would structure it based on how I am assuming you are using this. If the use cases changed or the requirements were not fully understood I would possibly write it a number of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would make a custom type, `Query`, and define these as methods on the prototype of `Query`.

```
var Query = function(...);
Query.prototype.removeStopWords = function (query){ ... }
Query.prototype.stemmer = function (query){ ... }
Query.prototype.convertBoolean = function (query){ ... }
```

So you can call it as

```
var query = new Query()
    .removeStopWords()
    .stemmer()
    .convertBoolean();
```

Comment: you can simplify this as `Query.prototype = { removeStopWords: function() { .. }, stemmer: function() { .. } ... };` I always like to add a `constructor` property to it as well. but it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is a good way, in alternative this is the pattern I use:

```
var QueryPreprocessing = {

  init: function () {

      // set config variables for closures here
      var initparam = 'whatever';

      return {

          removeStopWords: function (query) {
              //code here
          },

          stemmer: function (w) {
              //code here
          },

          convertBoolean: function (w) {
              //code here
          }
    }

}

var qp = QueryPreprocessing.init();
qp.removeStopWord('thequerystring');
//...
```

Comment: Thank you. How is this any better than other design patterns like the Factory or Facade?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  The only change I would make is possibly factoring our a new function:

```
queryPreprocess.preProcessQuery = function preprocessQuery(query) {
    query = queryPreprocessing.removeStopWords(query);
    query = queryPreprocessing.stemmer(query);
    query = queryPreprocessing.convertBoolean(query);
    return query;
};

var queryRaw = $("#textbox").val();
var queryProcessed = queryPreprocess.preprocessQuery(queryRaw);
```

An object or class seems like way too much mental overhead for this task of composing functions.